# Spring 4 ajax login redirect to requested url

Tags: ajax, spring, rest

This is part of my configuration

```
public class CustomWebSecurityConfigurer extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    private static final String LOGIN_URL = "/#login";
    @Override
    protected void configure(final HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        final String adminAccess = String.format("hasAnyRole('ROLE_%s', 'ROLE_%s')",
                Role.SYSTEM_ADMINISTRATOR, Role.USER_ADMINISTRATOR);
        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/admin/**").access(adminAccess).and().formLogin()
                .loginPage(LOGIN_URL);
    }
}
```

As one can see, the login just triggers the start page and #login is used to show a modal login dialogue, that sends login using AJAX.

The following code is the login.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.POST)
ResponseEntity<Map<String, Object>> login(@RequestBody final JSONCredentials credentials) {
    log.debug("Test: {}", requestCache == null ? "null" : requestCache.getClass());
    final Authentication auth = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(credentials.getUsername(),
            credentials.getPassword());
    final Authentication authenticated = authenticationManager.authenticate(auth);
    if (authenticated.isAuthenticated()) {
        SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authenticated);
        return get();
    }
    SecurityContextHolder.clearContext();
    throw new BadCredentialsException("");
}
```

it does the authentication and calls get method.

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
ResponseEntity<Map<String, Object>> get() {
    final Map<String, Object> result = new HashMap<>();
    final Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
    if (auth != null) {
        result.put("principal", auth.getPrincipal());
    }
    result.put("redirectTo", "URL where I come from");
    return ResponseEntity.ok(result);
}
```

So when I open /admin I am redirected to /#login. The login dialogue is opened and the login succeed but I like to redirect to the originally requested URL.
The original URL should be known by Spring, returned as a response of the AJAX login, and the JavaScript simply should change the location.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the meanwhile I implemented a solution that works very well for us.

First I created an AccessFilter, that checks if a redirect to the configured Login URL is taking place.

```
public class AccessFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {
    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(AccessFilter.class);

    @Inject private SessionContext ctx;
    @Inject private Environment env;

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(final HttpServletRequest request,
            final HttpServletResponse response, final FilterChain filterChain)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
        if (response.getStatus() == 302 && response.getHeaderNames().contains("Location")
                && response.getHeader("Location").contains("#login")) {
            final String vrkroot = env.getProperty("VRK_HOST_NAME");
            final String myRoot = vrkroot.replaceAll("^https?://.+?/", "/");
            final String redirect = myRoot + request.getServletPath().replaceFirst("/", "")
                    + (request.getQueryString() != null ? "?" + request.getQueryString() : "");
            log.debug("URL: {}, Query: {}, Redirect: {}", request.getRequestURL().toString(),
                    request.getQueryString(), redirect);
            ctx.setAfterLoginRedirect(redirect);
        }
    }
}
```

The environment variable `VRK_HOST_NAME` is used to define the real URL the system is using. This is necessary because the Tomcat 8 Server is behind an Apache Webserver that redirects to Tomcat Context.

```
http://www.mydomain.de/ > localhost:8080/<ContextRoot>
```

I found no other easy way to determine the actual URL.

myRoot contains the relative root of my application from the Apache point of view, not the Tomcat point. This is only relevant if my app is not in the root. MyAppName can be different then ContextRoot.

```
http://www.mydomain.de/MyAppName
```

Finally the redirect URL is calculated and stored in a Context Object / Variable.

```
@Component
@Scope(value = "session", proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)
public class SessionContext implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -8618385704526830047L;
    private String afterLoginRedirect;

    public String getAfterLoginRedirect() {
        return afterLoginRedirect;
    }

    public void setAfterLoginRedirect(final String afterLoginRedirect) {
        this.afterLoginRedirect = afterLoginRedirect;
    }
}
```

The last piece is the Controller, that handles the AJAX login.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.POST)
ResponseEntity<Map<String, Object>> login(@RequestBody final JSONCredentials credentials) {
    final Authentication auth = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(credentials.getUsername(),
            credentials.getPassword());
    final Authentication authenticated = authenticationManager.authenticate(auth);
    if (authenticated.isAuthenticated()) {
        SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authenticated);
        return get();
    }
    SecurityContextHolder.clearContext();
    throw new BadCredentialsException("");
}

@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
ResponseEntity<Map<String, Object>> get() {
    final Map<String, Object> result = new HashMap<>();
    final Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
    final HttpServletRequest request = ((ServletRequestAttributes) RequestContextHolder
            .getRequestAttributes()).getRequest();
    final CsrfToken csrfToken = (CsrfToken) request.getAttribute(CsrfToken.class.getName());
    final HttpServletResponse response = ((ServletRequestAttributes) RequestContextHolder
            .getRequestAttributes()).getResponse();
    response.addHeader("X-CSRF-TOKEN", csrfToken.getToken());
    if (auth != null) {
        result.put("principal", auth.getPrincipal());
        if (!Strings.isNullOrEmpty(ctx.getAfterLoginRedirect())) {
            result.put("redirectTo", ctx.getAfterLoginRedirect());
            ctx.setAfterLoginRedirect(null);
        }
    }
    return ResponseEntity.ok(result);
}
```

This both methods in a controller will do the login and return the info who am I at the moment. In the `get` method the redirect URL is send to the client and finally the JavaScript is doing the redirection.

Hope this is useful.